# How do I delete a mesh/object in the middle of my animation?

Tags: animation, objects

I'm an MC animator, and I am a noob. I want to create an animation where the world deletes, and the character falls into the main grid thing.

I use a MAC, and Blender 2.79b.

Comment: Hello, thanks for asking questions! But you're going to have to clarify with images, file, or details. Technical software is a precise art. The "World" could refer to a scene, everything on screen, an earth model, etc. So, please show an example, video, or screenshot. Or you can describe it using Blender terms. There will be less confusion and you will get a very accurate answer. PS- if you're using Cycles, go to Properties>Object. Scroll down to Cycles Settings>Ray Visibility>Settings>Camera. Right click>Insert Keyframe. You can keyframe any object to visible to the camera, then invisible.

Answer (score 7):

I think that one way to achieve what you want is to scale to 0 and very fast your world in order to create the illusion of disappearing. Like in the GIF below.

[image]

If you need more details about how i have made the animation please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer (by @FranciscoArleo) assumes you are using physics to animate the fall, and is the simplest solution if this is the case.

If you are hand animating then the scaling trick is not necessary, instead you can keyframe render visibility in the [outliner](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/outliner.html) by toggling the camera icon next to the object, and then right-clicking the camera icon and selecting insert keyframe.